# My Bootstrap Carousel doesn't change when i add a video into the slides?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, while-loop

I have a bootstrap carousel that works perfectly when i only have images included, but as soon as i add a video, my indicators don't work and i can't click through the remaining slides? Does anyone know what i've done wrong? Here is my code with a little bit of dodgy php:

```
echo "<div class='carousel-item";
  if ($caroselCount == "1") { echo " active"; }
echo "'>";

if($extraPicDetails['file_type'] == "image") {
  echo "<img src='Members/".$Details['file_name']."' alt='' style='margin: auto; display: block; background-color: #ffffff;'>";
}
elseif($extraPicDetails['file_type'] == "video") {
  echo "<video src='Members/".$Details['file_name']."' loop autoplay muted playsinline width='100%' style='display: block;'>";
}

echo "</div>";
$caroselCount = "0";
```

All works fine if i just loop through a bunch of pics, but if there are a couple of images and a video... NOPE! Can't click through the slides, can anyone help me please?

Here is the rendered code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class='carousel-item active'>
<video src='Members/44_Pic1_ezgifcomgifmaker.mp4' loop autoplay muted playsinline width='100%' style='display: block;'>
</div>
<div class='carousel-item'>
<img src='Members/44_Pic2_Polish_20200814_165321683.jpg' alt='' style='margin: auto; display: block; background-color: #ffffff;'>
</div>
<div class='carousel-item'>
<img src='Members/44_Pic1_image.jpg' alt='' style='margin: auto; display: block; background-color: #ffffff;'>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there no errors in your console log? If I'm right the carousel of bootstrap works on javascript/jquery so if you can't click through you probably have a js error thats breaks your slider, or do you have multiple sliders with the same ID

Comment: Nope, no errors at all. Never thought of that though, thank you!

Comment: Can you post the rendered html of the complete slider so people can try to reproduce the situation

Comment: Good thinking @Baracuda078 just added it above

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error but it works all fine. I downloaden a video and images from pixabay and loaded bootstrap 4 through cdn links. Instead of inline css I use the bootstrap class `img-fluid` to make the media fit better in the carousel, I disabled the indicators in my example.

Below the code I tested:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">

            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Indicators -->
                <!--        <ul class="carousel-indicators">-->
                <!--            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>-->
                <!--            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>-->
                <!--            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>-->
                <!--        </ul>-->

                <!-- The slideshow -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class='carousel-item active'>
                            <video src='media/Golden - 48569.mp4' loop autoplay muted playsinline class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class='carousel-item'>
                            <img src='media/20201102_14%20-%20Foto.jpg' alt='' class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class='carousel-item'>
                            <img src='media/20201102_17%20-%20Fotoe.jpg' alt='' class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you SO so much! really appreciate that, will try that now!